# I deleted package.json and Gruntfile.js and now Grunt will not load dependencies

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, powershell, gruntjs

So by accident I deleted my package.json and Gruntfile folder from my project directory and before I did that I already ran `grunt` and `grunt jshint` and it ran perfectly fine. I re-made both files (package.json and Gruntfile.js) and now when I try to run `grunt` or `grunt jshint` It tells me..

```
PS C:\Users\Vincent\desktop\projects\kittenbook> grunt jshint
>> Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-concat" not found. Is it installed?
>> Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-copy" not found. Is it installed?
>> Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-jshint" not found. Is it installed?
Warning: Task "jshint" not found. Use --force to continue.
```

Then Powershell crashes soon after.

Npm works I already checked and I know Grunt is obviously installed.

Here's my Gruntfile.js which I had to re-make. It ran perfectly fine before I deleted my package.json file..

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        concat: {
        release: {
            src: ['js/values.js', 'js/prompt.js'],
            dest: 'release/main.js'
        }
      },
      copy: {
          release: {
              src: 'manifest.json',
              dest: 'release/manifest.json'
          }
      },
      jshint: {
          files: ['js/values.js', 'js/prompt.js']
      }
    });

    // Load Grunt plugin
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');

    // Register tasks
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['jshint', 'concat', 'copy']);

};
```

Here's the new package.json file

```
{
  "name": "kittenbook",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "^0.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "^0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "^0.6.5",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^1.0.0"
  }

}
```

Also Should I run the Gruntfile above even though I already ran it the first time? Will that mess anything up?

I hope this is not too confusing. I'm new at programming. Thanks!

Update: When I try to run `npm install`

```
PS C:\Users\Vincent> cd desktop/projects/kittenbook
PS C:\Users\Vincent\desktop\projects\kittenbook> npm install
npm WARN package.json kittenbook@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json kittenbook@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json kittenbook@1.0.0 No README data
npm WARN package.json kittenbook@1.0.0 No license field.
```

UPDATE: The mistake I made was that the Gruntfile.js was outside of my projects folder.. Wow.. lol. Problem solved.

Comment: They're just warnings about missing "fields" in your `package.json`.

Answer (score 2):

In command prompt go to the directory of your project and run the following command.

```
npm install
```

You may have to open command prompt with administrator privileges for this to work.

This will install all the npm modules defined in the package.json file.